# Python: Objects throwing arguments warning in

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x, object

I ran into a problem. Through the below code I am trying to simplify several file/json objects in a large script.

> Pointer.py

```
import json

class Pointers:

    def __init__(self, target_file, mode, data):
        self.target_file = target_file              # file nameand path to load/store
        self.data = data                            # data to load/store
        self.mode = mode                            # mode on the data

    # some other functions

    # Writer object for non-json files
    def sys_writer_4file(self):
        with open(self.target_file, self.mode) as write_pointer:
            handler = write_pointer.write(self.data)
        write_pointer.close()
        return handler
```

But when I try calling it from another script like below,

> Report.py

```
from f_pointers import Pointer

class Something:

    def someElse(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def someNonStaticFunction(self):
        path = "./filepath/filename"
        someData = data
        Pointers.sys_writer_4file(("./filepath/filename", 'wb', somedata)
```

I get the unexpected argument warning from my interpreter saying,

> This inspection reports discrepancies between declared parameters and
>   actual arguments, as well as incorrect arguments (e.g. duplicate named
>   arguments) and incorrect argument order. Decorators are analyzed, too.

On this line:

```
Pointers.sys_writer_4file(("./filepath/filename", 'wb', somedata)
```

Can someone advise me how I should create the object? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to init your class first:

```
Pointers("./filepath/filename", 'wb', somedata).sys_writer_4file()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @SatanDmytro. I was initializing inside the function parameters - what a blunder!!